# Is this the correct way to use move references and unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've barely used the C++ move feature, so I'm not confident what I am doing is correct. I would appreciate anyone looking over my code and pointing out any mistakes I've made.

The idea is to create a map of resources stored by key. The resources may be non-copyable and non-movable.

Also, does my class need a constructor and destructor definition?

Thanks.

```
#define TYPE(x) std::identity<decltype(x)>::type

namespace General
{
    template<class T>
    std::string ToString(const T& x)
    {
        std::ostringstream ss;
        ss << x;
        return ss.str();
    }
}

namespace General
{
    template<class T, class KEY = std::string>
    class ResourceManager
    {
    public:
        typedef T ResourceType;
        typedef KEY KeyType;

        void Load(const KeyType& key, std::unique_ptr<ResourceType>&& resource);
        const ResourceType& Read(const KeyType& key) const;
        ResourceType& Modify(const KeyType& key);
        void Unload(const KeyType& key);
        std::unique_ptr<ResourceType>&& Release(const KeyType& key);
        void UnloadAll();

    private:
        std::map<KeyType, std::unique_ptr<ResourceType>> data;
    };
}

template<class T, class KEY>
void General::ResourceManager<T, KEY>::Load(const KeyType& key, std::unique_ptr<ResourceType>&& resource)
{
    auto find_it = data.lower_bound(key);
    if (find_it != data.end() && ! (data.key_comp()(key, find_it->first)))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(General::ToString(key) + " already exists!");
    }
    else
    {
        data.insert(find_it, TYPE(data)::value_type(key, std::move(resource)));
    }
}

template<class T, class KEY>
const typename General::ResourceManager<T, KEY>::ResourceType& General::ResourceManager<T, KEY>::Read(const KeyType& key) const
{
    auto find_it = data.find(key);
    if (find_it == data.end())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(General::ToString(key) + " could not be found!");
    }
    else
    {
        return *find_it->second;
    }
}

template<class T, class KEY>
typename General::ResourceManager<T, KEY>::ResourceType& General::ResourceManager<T, KEY>::Modify(const KeyType& key)
{
    auto find_it = data.find(key);
    if (find_it == data.end())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(General::ToString(key) + " could not be found!");
    }
    else
    {
        return *find_it->second;
    }
}

template<class T, class KEY>
void General::ResourceManager<T, KEY>::Unload(const KeyType& key)
{
    auto find_it = data.find(key);
    if (find_it == data.end())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(General::ToString(key) + " could not be found!");
    }
    else
    {
        data.erase(find_it);
    }
}

template<class T, class KEY>
std::unique_ptr<typename General::ResourceManager<T, KEY>::ResourceType>&& General::ResourceManager<T, KEY>::Release(const KeyType& key)
{
    auto find_it = data.find(key);
    if (find_it == data.end())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(General::ToString(key) + " could not be found!");
    }
    else
    {
        auto resource = std::move(find_it->second);
        data.erase(find_it);
        return std::move(resource);
    }
}

template<class T, class KEY>
void General::ResourceManager<T, KEY>::UnloadAll()
{
    data.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simplified piece of code that demonstrates the crux of your situation and how to write the code idiomatically:

```
std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<Foo>> m;

void add_to_map(int key, std::unique_ptr<Foo> val)
{
    m[key] = std::move(val);
}
```

Usage:

```
add_to_map(1, std::unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(1, 2, 3)));

std::unique_ptr<Foo> p(new Foo(true, 'x'));
p->mutate();
add_to_map(std::move(p));
```

Basically, pass the unique pointer (or any other movable-only type, for that matter) by *value* and move from it.

---

One special situation I've encountered is when you want to take ownership of an object *conditionally*. In that case, pass the unique pointer by reference and inspect it afterwards:

```
void add_maybe(std::unique_ptr<Foo> & val)
{
    if (rand() % 2 == 0)
    {
        m[12] = std::move(val);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> p(new Foo(true, 'x'));

add_maybe(p);

if (p) { /* we still own the resource            */ }
else   { /* the resource is now owned by the map */ }
```

---

Update: To release an object from the map, return by value:

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> release(int key)
{
    auto it = m.find(key);
    return it == m.end() ? { } : std::move(it->second);
}
```

Comment: So caller to the function should explicitly move his object to my value parameter?

Comment: @NeilKirk: If the caller has an lvalue, then yes. Otherwise it's implicit and no extra code is needed (as in the first usage example). And that example should be `add_to_map(std::make_unique<Foo>(1,2,3));` really, though that requires C++14.

Comment: What about the return type of the Release function?

Comment: Also by value, `std::unique_ptr<ResourceType>`. Basically, everything always by value, except for some exceptions.